# Generate a graph to exact size using Kronecker product graph model

Tags: graphs, computation-models, matrices

In network science, we can take sample a complex system and derive from this sampling a representative network (or graph) that describes the system to some extent. A model of a network, is a powerful mathematical abstraction of the observed system. The model can be used to generate networks similar to the observed network, i.e., synthetic models will have similar network characteristics.

Learning a model of a network is done with exponential random graph model and Kronecker product graph model. The latter is described in a series of papers like this [one](http://cs.stanford.edu/~jure/pubs/kronecker-jmlr10.pdf). [KronFit](https://snap.stanford.edu/snap/download.html) is a software tool that processes the graph/network of reference and learns/derives a set of parameter for the model to grow/generate synthetic graphs. In the case of Kronecker product graphs, the software is used to find the parameters of the model, aka a seed 2x2 matrix.

However, you can only build graphs where the size of the synthetic graphs is forced to powers of 2. Is there an extension to this model that grows graphs to exact size without padding the input? For example, if my original graph has 10000 nodes, how do I generate a network using the Kronecker product to exactly 10000 nodes?  In the classical way, I would have to pad my original graph with disconnected nodes to a total size of 2^14 nodes that's over 50% more nodes.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). Thank you!

Comment: I am not asking for software packages, I'm looking for modifications to the original generative network model that learns its parameters from observed data.

Comment: If you "pad" your graph and the learn parameters, you are learning the wrong parameters. Don't do that. It might be better to take a random induced subgraph of size 8192. Check also what other people did (people on the caliber of the original authors) – I'm sure they had the same problem.

Comment: They (Leskovec et al.) suggest you pad, if I read it correctly.  I searched for other papers that might have developed an 'extension' to the original model, but I haven't found much.